# Trying to extract data through bind variables in cx_oracle python

Tags: python-3.x, cx-oracle, bind-variables

I am trying execute below block of code with cx_oracle by bind variables, but getting below mentioned error everytime. Not sure what is missing.

## Anyone has idea on this

Code :

a = input("Please enter your name ::")

conn = cx_Oracle.connect('hello/123@oracle')
cur = conn.cursor()

text1 = "select customer from visitors where  name = :myvalue;"
cur.execute(text1,myvalue=str(a))

ERROR observed :
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Answer (score 0):

Remove the semi-colon at the end of your SQL statement.